# TikZ and autobreak package error

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I recently decided to give the autobreak package a try in a long document with lots of TikZ figures but couldn't get it to compile (using lualatex or pdflatex.)  I've narrowed it down just the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Without the autobreak package this compiles just fine.
\usepackage{autobreak}

\begin{document}

  % Works if I replace align* by equation* environment.
  \begin{align*}                                                                                              
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Putting the next two lines on one makes the error go away.
      \node{}
        child {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Any idea what's going on here?  Is this a bug in autobreak or am I missing something?

**edit:** I forgot to include the error message...

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17   \end{align*}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on autobreak-test.log.
```

Comment: I would say that almost certainly this is a bug. You are just loading the package, not even using `\begin{autobreak}...\end{autobreak}`.

Comment: It does look that way.  Just placing comment symbols `%` at line endings to turn all tikz statements into single-line statements avoids the issue, so that's what I'm doing for now.

Answer (score 1):

`autobreak` installs [a piece of code](https://github.com/tueda/autobreak/blob/8ff169664e89fbdee89cfa1fb12769cc6521318a/autobreak.dtx#L866-L878) into `align` for achieving its purpose, which changes the catcode of the line break character inside the `align` environment. Then the line break character is tokenized as a control sequence that is expanded as space. This is usually harmless in math mode because anyway spaces are ignored. Unfortunately, this seems fatally problematic for TikZ figures at the corner case you found: putting `\space` instead of a line break gives the same error `No shape named  is known`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{} \space child {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8   \node{} \space child {};
```